# Should I delete one of my questions that was closed as "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have an older question, [Maximum CASE Statements in a SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13615729/maximum-of-case-statements-in-query), which was closed as being "too localized". I ultimately found the answer (it was closed before I could post as an answer) but *I am sure that it will not be of any help to anyone* as the answer doesn't really fit the question.

Should I delete it?

Comment: I think so, if it won't help anyone else. If you don't plan on editing it to get it reopened it will just stay there like that forever, anyways. And I highly doubt you are in any danger of being question banned for deleting it. ;)